# Conferir dados recebidos pelo usuário

Tags: c

Como eu posso conferir se o usuário digitou um dado da forma que eu estou esperando?

Por exemplo, eu quero que ele digite um valor inteiro. Como sei se o valor que ele digitou foi um inteiro e não um `char` ou `float`, e caso a entrada não seja um inteiro, mande uma mensagem de erro e continue pedindo um inteiro?

Ainda não comecei a escrever o código.

Comment: A ideia do site é dar uma diretriz para o que você já está fazendo e não exatamente oferecer uma solução pronta. Sugiro que veja uns tutoriais de como ler inputs em C e vai fazendo.

Comment: Pode colocar um `if` para verificar o tipo de dado que a pessoa inseriu.

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples:

```
int eh_inteiro(const char *c) {
    int i = c[0] == '-' || c[0] == '+';
    if (!c[i]) return 0;
    while (c[i]) {
        if (c[i] < '0' || c[i] > '9') return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Aqui vai um teste para ela:

```
void testar(const char *c) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", c, eh_inteiro(c) ? "Sim" : "Não");
}

int main(void) {
    testar("123");
    testar("+123");
    testar("-123");
    testar("1");
    testar("0");
    testar("9");
    testar("999999");
    testar("-5");
    testar("-");
    testar("+");
    testar("");
    testar("banana");
    testar("123a");
    testar("12a3");
    testar(" ");
    testar(" 12");
    testar("12 ");
    testar("1 2");
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
123: Sim
+123: Sim
-123: Sim
1: Sim
0: Sim
9: Sim
999999: Sim
-5: Sim
-: Não
+: Não
: Não
banana: Não
123a: Não
12a3: Não
 : Não
 12: Não
12 : Não
1 2: Não
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/KNOUnD)